# Using an external file change as trigger

Tags: drake-r-package

I'm using `drake` to orchestrate a workflow where if an external shiny app  (stored in `project_dir/shiny/app.R`) changes, I want to trigger a docker build.

```r
shiny_plan <- drake_plan(

  docker_build = system(command = "docker build shiny/. -t docker.com/my-dash")

)
```

How do I detect a change in `app.R` to trigger target `docker_build`, given that `drake` does not help create `app.R`?

Best

Comment: Update: you may be interested in dynamic files: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/pull/1178. Brand new in development `drake` (the GitHub version, `remotes::install_github("ropensci/drake")).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `file_in()` wherever you want.

```r
shiny_plan <- drake_plan(
  docker_build = {
    file_in("app.R")
    system(command = "docker build shiny/. -t docker.com/my-dash")
  }
)
```

Alternatively, you could make the Docker build depend on the UI and server objects. That way, Docker will not trigger unnecessarily if all you do is change the comments or whitespace in your app code.

```r
shiny_plan <- drake_plan(
  docker_build = {
    ui
    server
    system(command = "docker build shiny/. -t docker.com/my-dash")
  }
)
```